# How to query for a specific part of a string field with SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is it possible to build a query/SELECT-Statement with SQL like that:

```
SELECT name
FROM MyTable
WHERE name[2] = 'x'
```

Comment: In Standard SQL there's `SUBSTRING(name FROM 2 FOR 1) = 'x'`, a syntax variation is  `SUBSTR(name, 2, 1) = 'x'`, one of those usually exists in all DBMSes...

Comment: Sorry, couldn't find the word "substring" in my head. Then http://duckduckgo.com whould have been enough. ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE substr(name, 2, 1) = 'x'
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9eecb7/359)